# udpate nested array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here is  my nested array i want to update section_name of  "sec b" to "section b" in "class_name":"second class" from sections array,        `

```
[
            {
                "classes": [
                    {
                        "class_name": "fist class",
                        "sections": [
                            {
                                "section_name": "section a"
                            },{
                                "section_name": "section b"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "class_name": "second class",
                        "sections": [
                            {
                                "section_name": "sect a"
                            },
                            {
                                "section_name": "sec b"
                            },
                            {
                                "section_name": "sec c"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": "testing",
            }
        ]
```

I want to update section name for particular class name,
I tried in many ways using filters also can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) with [$s[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_%5B%3Cidentifier%3E%5D) the positional operator

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {},
    {
        $set: {
            'classes.$[elem1].sections.$[elem2].section_name': 'section b'
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {'elem1.class_name': 'second class'},
            {"elem2.section_name": "sec b"},
        ]
    })
```